# Bootstrap3 and Select2 styling issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm experiencing some styling issues when using Select2 in combination with Bootstrap 3. I found out all about the [Select2 Bootstrap 3 CSS](https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/index.html) but I can't get it to work properly.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5nyV.png) is how it looks like.

As you can see it's too wide, the search glyphicon doesn't seem to appear and the placeholder isn't showing either.

This is how my code looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/select2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/select2-bootstrap.css">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<br />
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>General data</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRequester" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Requester</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputRequester" placeholder="Requester" value="@System.Environment.UserName" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="datepickerino" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Delivery date</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="datepickerino">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputProject" class="col-lg-2 control-label">State</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select id="inputProject" class="form-control input-sm select2">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    ...
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.2/select2.js"></script>
<script>
    $( ".select2" ).select2( { placeholder: "Select a State", maximumSelectionSize: 6} );
</script>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you're using a version of Select2 that is no longer supported. It's at least two years old, if not more.

Answer (score 0):

After another couple of hours it looks like I solved most of my issues:

Fixed the width by adding a width attribute to the JS code:

```
$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a country',
    maximumSelectionSize: 6,
    width: 'resolve'
});
```

Fixed the placeholder by adding an empty option to my select:

```
<option></option>
```

Still can't get the search glyphicon to show up tho.